# Resultant vector off a pair of cell arrays

Tags: matlab, if-statement

New to boolean logic in MatLab but I have variables u and v which are cell arrays (1 x 2928 long) with cell matrices of 58 x 58 with u and v values (for the wind) respectively. I need to use the equations given to calculate the resultant vector (wind direction) using the following equation but I CANNOT figure this out! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
for i = 1:2928
    if (v > 0) 
        direction {i} = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u/v)) + 180);
    elseif (u < 0 and v < 0);
        direction {i} = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u/v)) + 0);
    else (u > 0 and v < 0);
        direction {i} = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u/v)) + 360);
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Advice: never say urgent here, because people give voluntary contribution based on their availability. To help them helping you, when you tried something, always say the error or the side behavior your are getting. When you do this, they guess the problem before looking at your code and you have more chance to get an answer. Having say this, what is the problem with your code? What is the error returned by matlab? What is the unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the calculations element by element using a for loop you need to also specify the v(i) and u(i) elements.

```
for i = 1:2928
   if (v(i) > 0) 
      direction(i) = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u(i)/v(i))) + 180);
   elseif (u(i) < 0 && v(i) < 0);
      direction(i) = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u(i)/v(i))) + 0);
   else (u(i) > 0 && v(i) < 0);
      direction(i) = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u(i)/v(i))) + 360);
   end
end
```

There is a simpler and more elegant way to do the same calculations as above but without the for loop.

Try this:

```
direction(v>0) = ((180 / pi) * arctan((u(v>0)./v(v>0))) + 180);
```

do the same for the other conditions.  Use && instead of 'and' and || if you want 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`atan2()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html).  This function does the quadrant correction which I think you are trying to achieve with your `if` statement. Try this:

```
direction{i} = (180 / pi) * atan2(u{i},v{i});
```